# Blazor Server Initiating Task Halts Application

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor, task

I have a Blazor Server app that calls a number of APIs.  Everything works fine, but I am trying to wrap these calls in Tasks.  As soon as my code gets to the call, everything just stops.  I am sure I am doing something stupid, but no end of Googling is finding me the solution.  The call comes from a Syncfusion Grid when selecting a row.  Here is my minimum reproducable code:

```
public static IEnumerable<Quotation> customerQuotations = Array.Empty<Quotation>();

public async Task CustomerRowSelectHandler(RowSelectEventArgs<Customer> args)
{
    GetCustomerQuotes(args.Data.customerId);
}

static async void GetCustomerQuotes(int customerId)
    {
        string url = string.Format(@"https://my.server.dns/quotations/customer/{0}", customerId);
        var task = GetJsonString(url);
        task.Wait();
        customerQuotations = (IEnumerable<Quotation>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Quotation>(task.Result);
    }

private static async Task<string> GetJsonString(string url)
    {
        var TCS = new TaskCompletionSource<string>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
        var myClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
        HttpResponseMessage response = await myClient.GetAsync(url);
        string streamResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        TCS.SetResult(streamResponse);
        return await TCS.Task;
    }
```

If I do this how I am doing all of my other calls, i.e. not using a Task, it works fine, so I know it's not a silly error, it's something I am missing in my Task call.

Thanks in anticipation of any help offered.

Comment: Always avoid `async void`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem, is `Task.Wait()`. That can deadlock.

```
public async Task CustomerRowSelectHandler(RowSelectEventArgs<Customer> args)
{
    //GetCustomerQuotes(args.Data.customerId);
    await GetCustomerQuotes(args.Data.customerId);
}

//static async void GetCustomerQuotes(int customerId)
    async Task GetCustomerQuotes(int customerId)
    {
        string url = string.Format(@"https://my.server.dns/quotations/customer/{0}", customerId);
        var task = GetJsonString(url);
        // task.Wait();
        await task;
        customerQuotations = (IEnumerable<Quotation>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Quotation>(task.Result);
    }
```

and of course

```
var task = GetJsonString(url);
await task;
   ... (task.Result)
```

can (should) become

```
string result = await GetJsonString(url);
    ...  (result)
```

And when you don't need the response object (for status code etc) then all this can be done in 1 line:

```
customerQuotations = await myClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Quotation[]>(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are overcomplicating the async coding in the API call.  Why do you need to construct a `TaskCompletionSource`?   You may have reasons, but they are not evident in the code in your question.

Why not something like this:

```cs
    public async Task CustomerRowSelectHandler(...)
    {
        await GetCustomerQuotes(...);
    }

    private async ValueTask GetCustomerQuotes(...)
    {
        string url = string.Format(@"....");
        var http = new HttpClient(...);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(url);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            customerQuotations = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<Quotation>>() ?? Enumerable.Empty<Quotation>(); ;
       // handle errors
    }
```

Or even this, but you loose the error trapping.

```cs
customerQuotations = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<Quotation>>(url);
```

You should also consider using the `IHttpClientFactory` to manage http instances.

Comment: MrC - thank you so much for taking the time to help me out.  I am not a developer, just a bloke trying to get by, so when people with more experience go to this trouble, it really means a lot.  Thanks again.

Comment: Just for completeness, the TaskCompletionSource came from another article I was following.  That is now gone, another reason to thank MrC!  Trying to implement IHttpClientFactory, and getting an error, which I have posted here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75334007/system-argumentnullexception-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-factory-when-i

Comment: TaskCompletionSource is for more specialist and advanced  situations.  Totally unnecessary here.  See you sorted your issue.

Comment: Every day is a learning day! Thanks once again for your help.