# System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'factory') when implementing IHTTPClientFactory

Tags: blazor, httpclient, .net-7.0

Following on from this question:
[Blazor Server Initiating Task Halts Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75321856/blazor-server-initiating-task-halts-application/75326255)
I am now trying to implement the IHttpClientFactory DI as recommended.  I am following this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0
and I am getting this error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'factory')
    at System.ThrowHelper.Throw(String paramName)
    at System.Net.Http.HttpClientFactoryExtensions.CreateClient(IHttpClientFactory factory)
    at DespatchProServer.Pages.Customers.CustomersHome.GetCustomerQuotes(Int32 customerId) in C:\path\to\CustomersHome.razor.cs:line 246
    at my.dot.notation.CustomersHome.CustomerRowSelectHandler(RowSelectEventArgs`1 args) in C:\path\to\CustomersHome.razor.cs:line 137
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
    at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Internal.Selection`1.SelectByRow(Row`1 rowToSelect, MouseAndKeyArgs evt)
    at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Internal.Selection`1.ValidateRowSelectionClick(Row`1 row, MouseAndKeyArgs e)
    at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Internal.Selection`1.RowSelectionClickHandler(MouseAndKeyArgs e, ValueTuple`3 target)
    at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Internal.Selection`1.ClickHandler(MouseEventArgs e, ValueTuple`3 target)
    at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Internal.GridCellBase`1.CellClickHandler(MouseEventArgs e, Boolean IsCheckBox)
    at Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Internal.GridCell`1.<BuildRenderTree>b__0_5(MouseEventArgs e)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

In Program.cs I have:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
```

And here is my minimum reproducible code:

```
public partial class CustomersHome
{

    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public CustomersHome() { }

    public CustomersHome(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) => _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;

    public IEnumerable<Quotation> customerQuotations = Array.Empty<Quotation>();

    public async Task CustomerRowSelectHandler(RowSelectEventArgs<Customer> args)
    {
        await GetCustomerQuotes(args.Data.customerId);
    }
        public async ValueTask GetCustomerQuotes(int customerId)
    {
        string url = string.Format(@"https://my.server.dns/quotations/customer/{0}", customerId);

        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(
        HttpMethod.Get,
        url)
        {
            Headers =
            {
                { HeaderNames.Accept, "application/vnd.github.v3+json" },
                { HeaderNames.UserAgent, "HttpRequestsSample" }
            }
        };
        
        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(); **-> This is line 246**
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            customerQuotations = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<Quotation>>() ?? Enumerable.Empty<Quotation>(); ;
        }
    }
}
```

The call comes from a Syncfusion Grid on row select, not that I think that has any bearing on the outcome.  Any pointers gratefully received.

Comment: You have 2 ctors. Are you sure that the second one with parameter is called? How `CustomersHome` is instantiated/called?

Comment: Also not sure that making `customerQuotations` a static field is a good idea.

Comment: @GuruStron - Thanks for your feedback.  I am not a developer, so this stuff is tough for me.  I tried taking out the parameterless constructor, but then the solution does not run, and the error is there is no parameterless constructor.....  So how to I ensure that?

Comment: Where is exactly you see the error? It seems that for some reason you are creating `CustomersHome` instead of injecting it. Without seeing the full code it is hard to tell.

Comment: The error happens when I click a row on my grid.  CustomersHome is my razor component, I am going to guess that is where I am going wrong.  Should I extract that code to another class and inject my new class?  Thanks again for your help, really appreciate it

Comment: Without seeing the full code I can't help much more.

Comment: Remove the parameterless constructor `CustomersHome()`.

Comment: Thanks @vernou, but when I do that it errors with "No parameterless constructor".  I think the problem is I am trying to do this in my code behind for a razor component.  I am not clever enough to extract this elsewhere and do it properly, and it's really too much to ask anyone on here to help me do that.  Thanks for your suggestion though, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OK, got to the bottom of this.  Bear in mind, I am not a developer, so don't laugh too much at me.  On my razor page, added:

```
@inject IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory
```

Then on my code behind page changed the line:

```
var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
```

To

```
var httpClient = ClientFactory.CreateClient();
```

and removed the constructors at the top of the class.  Working perfectly now.